# How to exclude certain columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataset in a .csv file:

```
feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4
0, 42, 2, 1000
2, 13, ?, 997
1, 30, ?, 861
2, 29, ?, ?
```

I would like to create a pandas dataframe or a numpy array where I don't have the features with an x% of unknown data (where x was specified previously in code).

Comment: The question is no clear to me , can you show the expected output

Comment: For an example of 0% of admission of missing data, I would like to save only feature1, feature2 and their respective data to my pandas dataframe

For 25%, feature4 also would be included

Comment: So, you're trying to replace all the `?` with something? Is that your question?

Comment: No, I have to exclude the features in which there's too much '?' from my analysis.

Comment: are they question marks or `NaN` values. This is important because the dataframe currently has mixed types

Comment: They're a char value '?'. And yes, the dataframe is mixed. Actually, in my problem, I have strings too, but it's out of the topic of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `replace` and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) (PS, you need using the parameter thresh in dropna )

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.replace('?', np.NaN).dropna(axis=1,thresh=0.75*len(df)) # for you example , we only accpet one NA here

Out[735]: 
   feature1  feature2  feature4
0         0         1     100.0
1         2         2     900.0
2         1         3     861.0
3         2         4       NaN
```

---

Data Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': [0,2,1,2], 'feature2': [1,2,3,4],'feature3':[2,'?','?','?'],'feature4':[100,900,861,'?']})
```

Comment: Wow, it seems like this is kind of a bug in SO site. You posted an answer earlier, then deleted it. I kept the page open while I was working on my answer and kept checking if anyone answered already. But, the page didn't display your answer because, I guess, you "undeleted" your original answer. SO didn't show any new answers. So, I had no way of knowing that anyone answered already.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume those `'?'` are null values.  If they aren't, do something like this:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Now, we can make a function that takes a dataframe and a threshold.  What we want to do is use `loc` with a boolean series that tells us which columns have sufficient data representation.

```
drp = lambda d, x: d.loc[:, d.isnull().mean() < x]

drp(df, .5)

   feature1  feature2  feature4
0         0        42    1000.0
1         2        13     997.0
2         1        30     861.0
3         2        29       NaN
```

---

If you insist that `'?'` stay that way... and we can also include `NaN`

```
d = df.mask(df.astype(object).eq('?'))

drp = lambda d, x: d.loc[:, d.isnull().mean() < x]

drp(d, .5)
```

Comment: The OP actually said in his comment that the `?` are not null values.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the easiest way to solve it, that if I understand your question correctly.
You can change `?` to `NaN` using `np.nan`, then use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [df.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) to select the columns you need.

```
df.replace(to_replace= '\?', value=np.nan, inplace=True, regex=True)
df = df.loc[:, (df.isnull().sum() <= len(df) / 4)]
print (df)
        feature1  feature2  feature4
0         0         42      1000
1         2         13       997
2         1         30       861
3         2         29       NaN
```